# Adapting code to viewDidLoad instead of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this code that I was previously calling inside a UITableView method

`-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

---

However, I now want to use this inside viewDidLoad but of course this code won't work becayse it's using objectatIndex:.row - What do I need to change in my code to make this work in viewDidLoad

```
SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) [_products objectAtIndex:.row];

_priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[_priceFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[_priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
labelPrice.text = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
```

Comment: FYI - please stop using the xcode tag unless your question actually is about using Xcode.

Comment: Pass whatever number you want to get the desired product. If you want the 1st one pass in `0` instead of `indexPath.row`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the `indexPath.row` with the number of the index of the object you want. For example if you want the first object just use:

```
SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) [_products objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got an iVar declared for your price formatter. If that is the case, then put this code in viewDidLoad:

```
_priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[_priceFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[_priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
```

This is more efficient, because we can use the same NSNumberFormatter for each cell, instead of creating new ones all the time.

Then, you can put this code in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) [_products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
labelPrice.text = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
```

Comment: I dont need to use a UITableView anymore, I am trying to do this in a UIViewController

Comment: you can probably use _products.firstObject